# Why does the value of the variable change?

Tags: python, numpy

Here is the minimal version of my code:

```
SP=np.array([[-0.4,.2,1],[-.34,.31,1],[-.22,-.2,0],[.8,.25,0],[.92,-.42,1]])

dt=0.1

SP0=SP[:,0]
print("SP0 = ",SP0)
SP[:,0]=SP[:,0]*cos(dt)+SP[:,1]*sin(dt)
print("SP0 = ", SP0)
SP[:,1]=SP[:,1]*cos(dt)-SP0*sin(dt)
```

OUTPUT:

```
SP0 =  [-0.4  -0.34 -0.22  0.8   0.92]
SP0 =  [-0.37803498 -0.30735306 -0.2388676   0.82096169  0.8734738 ]
```

As can be seen above, I am trying to evolve `SP[:,0]` and `SP[:,1]` depending on their previous values but in order to put the previous value of `SP[:,0]` in `SP[:,1]` (since it gets changed before moving on to `SP[:,1]` ) I first store it in `SP0`.

But this doesn't seem to make any difference because the value of `SP0` also changes to the new `SP[:,0]` after I change `SP[:,0]` later. But this is weird since `SP[:,0]` only changes after I store it's value in `SP0`.

Why is this happening and how do I evolve the `SP[:,1]` and `SP[:,0]` correctly?

Comment: use `SP0=np.copy(SP[:,0])` to get a copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy slices don't create new arrays; they return views into the original array. Modifying either will affect the other.

To keep the previous value, call `.copy()` on the view:

```python3
SP0=SP[:,0].copy()
```

Comment: Thanks. Will `SP[:,0]` also change after the change in `SP[:,1]` . So basically after the last line in the code in my question if I `print(SP[:,0])` would it have changed? (it doesn't change but why not ?)

Answer (score 0):

Reusing variable names is usually seen as a bad practice in Python.

In your case I would suggest, that you simply assign your manipulated array to a new variable.
This should solve your issue, as you can then simply reference your initial values in your next calculation step.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy arrays are referenced when sliced that means modification will update all references, so copy the content

so you can either call `np.copy(SP[:,0])` or `SP[:,0].copy()` whichever you feel easy for you.

**Working Example**

```
import numpy as np
import math as m

SP=np.array([[-0.4,.2,1],[-.34,.31,1],[-.22,-.2,0],[.8,.25,0],[.92,-.42,1]])

dt=0.1

SP0 = np.copy(SP[:,0])
print("SP0 = ", SP0)
SP[:,0] = SP[:,0] * m.cos(dt) + SP[:,1] * m.sin(dt)

print("SP0 = ", SP0)
SP[:,1] = SP[:,1] * m.cos(dt) - SP0 * m.sin(dt)
```

Output

```
SP0 =  [-0.4  -0.34 -0.22  0.8   0.92]
SP0 =  [-0.4  -0.34 -0.22  0.8   0.92]
```